# why oracle can not startup, log error ora-27047

Tags: oracle

when sqlplus startup oracle
this is the log:

```
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1068937216 bytes
Fixed Size          2260088 bytes
Variable Size         671089544 bytes
Database Buffers      390070272 bytes
Redo Buffers            5517312 bytes
ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info
```

```
ORA-00202: control file: '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_01/dbs/ora_control2.ctl'
ORA-27047: unable to read the header block of file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 25: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Additional information: 1
ORA-00210: cannot open the specified control file
ORA-00202: control file: '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_01/dbs/ora_control1.ctl'
ORA-27047: unable to read the header block of file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 25: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Additional information: 1
ORA-205 signalled during: ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT...
```

thanks

fix this problem fix this problem

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions; this is not a programming question and is off-topic for StackOverflow. You should ask it at https://dba.stackexchange.com